# navicat mysql 1064 error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to create a stored procedure by using navicat premium. I clicked functions button then choosed stored procedure choice. on the advanced tab it wants me to write begin end part of teh sql code. I wrote this
***BEGIN
UPDATE TABLE trl_profile SET trl_profile.type = type WHERE trl_profile.profile_id =profile_id;
END;***

in the sql preview tab it creates this sql

***CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN type varchar,IN profile_id int)
BEGIN
UPDATE TABLE trl_profile SET trl_profile.type = type WHERE trl_profile.profile_id = profile_id;
END;;***

i save it and gives the error
http://m.friendfeed-media.com/2974c2eb28242939014b14171fbc2a32278c3bbb

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR` requires a length AFAIK. Does this work?

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `NewProc` (IN type varchar(64), IN -- etc)
```

How you get navicat to play ball is a whole other matter, never used it, so I wouldn't know how to whip it into shape.